# Mathematics of Cap Charging Circuit

Tags: capacitor, boost, converter, math

To teach myself the basics of power electronics I've been trying to build a circuit, which charges up a capacitor to a voltage higher than the input voltage. Basically it's a boost converter with no load.
I've run a simulation in LTSpice and found that the simulation results during the "switch-open phase" do not match my predictions at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT8fTQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Prediction

When the switch is open, the circuit is basically an LC circuit with a superimposed DC voltage source. Therefore I set up and solved a differential equation and ended up with this:

$$
i(t) = I_{L,0} \cdot \cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{LC}}) - \frac{C(V_{C,0}-V_{in})}{\sqrt{LC}} \sin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{LC}})
$$
\$I_{L,0}\$ is the inductor current when the switch opens
\$V_{C,0}\$ is the capacitor voltage
\$V_{in}\$ is the input voltage

Since there's still a diode in the circuit, of course there won't be any oscillation. Which is why I expected to see only the beginning of an oscillation, as modelled by the above equation, until the current hits zero. I then plugged in my component values and numerically solved for \$t\$.

### Result

The simulation yields an almost linear decay of the current. The time that it takes to reach zero is nowhere near the time that my math predicted.
Using the component values from the schematic, the mathematical model yields a time of **1.92ms** until the current hits zero.
In LTSpice however, it only took **396 us**.

[image]

So where did I screw up?
Thanks in advance

Comment: mH - milliHenry (1/1000 H), mF milliFarad (1000 microFarads)

Comment: What you are doing is the start-up analysis of the circuit, including initial conditions. Something similar to what is done with thyristors with RL load. For switch converters, normally the literature deals with the equations in steady-state and small signal. Small signal analisys: Time-varying currents and voltages in the circuit, have a small magnitude compared to the DC bias currents and voltages.

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr By steady-state and small signal do you mean the assumption that the cap is already charged and sufficiently large so that the output voltage remains mostly constant?

Comment: What switching frequency are you using for the FET gate?

Comment: @user96037 about 2.2 kHz

Comment: @Mathis: Yes. Variations around an operating point.

Comment: @Mathis Unless it's already there, retry the simulation with either `Start external DC supply voltages at 0V`, or `Skip initial operating point solution` checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current decay will be approximately linear if the voltage change on the capacitor is small on each cycle.

Remember that the voltage (V) across and inductor L is V = L * di/dt (where di/dt is the rate of change of inductor current with time).  If V changes by only a small percentage during a switching cycle, and L is constant then di/dt must be approximatly constant as well during that cycle.  Constant di/dt corresponds to a linear change in current.

Note that during the portion of the switching cycle where the MOSFET is open the voltage V is equal to the capacitor voltage plus a diode drop.  So as long as the change in capacitor voltage dV during one cycle is small the condition for approximately linear current decay is satisfied.  The conditions for approximately constant current decay can be met at fairly low output voltages in your case.

If the inductor current is allowed to decay to 0 during each cycle then the change in capacitor voltage dV during each cycle can be calculated using the total stored energy of the components.

The energy (E_C) stored in a capacitor (C) having voltage V is...
E_C = 0.5 * C * V^2

The energy (E_L) stored in an inductor (L) having current (I) is...
E_L = 0.5 * I ^2 * L

During one switching cycle where E_L goes from E_L_inital to 0 the total energy is preserved (ignoring the diode and resistive losses), so...

E_C_final = E_C_initial + E_L_initial

Therefore...

0.5 * C * V_C_final^2 = 0.5 * C * V_C_initial^2 + 0.5 * I_L_initial^2 * L

V_C_final is the final capacitor voltage
V_C_initial is the initial capacitor voltage
I_L_initial is the peak inductor current

Solving for V_C_final gives...

V_C_final = sqrt(V_C_initial^2 + I_L_initial^2 * L/C)

Therefore dV is...

dV = V_C_final - V_C_initial = sqrt(V_C_initial^2 + I_L_initial^2 * L/C) - V_C_initial

For example if C is 1.5mF and L is 1mH (as in your schematic), and capacitor voltage is 2.5V at the start of the cycle and the peak inductor current is 1A then...

dV = sqrt(2.5V^2 + 1A^2 * 1mH/1.5mF) - 2.5V = 128mV

Since 128mV is only 5% of 2.5V so in this example the current decay rate will only vary by about 5% as the inductor current goes from 1A to 0A.

Assuming approximately constant output voltage the time (T) for the inductor current to go to zero is...

T = I_L_Initial * L / (V_C_initial + 0.7V)

Overall as the capacitor charges the current will get more and more linear and the inductor discharge time will get shorter and shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! So apparently it really does not behave like an LC circuit when discharging...
One more question: In the last equation that you wrote down, did you mean to type I_L_Initial * L instead of I_L_Initial / L?

Comment: @Mathis Yes you are correct.  The time would be proportional to the inductor value.  I will correct that.

Answer (score 6):

> Basically it's a boost converter with no load

Here's your first problem. A theoretical boost converter with no load produces infinite output voltage. Basically it's a power converter - you put energy into the inductor and release that energy into the capacitor. Without a load, the output voltage will continue to rise for each switching cycle.

> I've run a simulation in LTSpice and found that the simulation results
>   during the "switch-open phase" do not match my predictions at all

Using a 1N400x diode is a poor choice - the reverse switch off time of circa 30 us means extremely poor performance. Use a diode that can handle fast switching.

Also we do not know what your predictions are.

> So where did I screw up?

Possibly on the two points above.

Comment: I understand that the voltage will keep rising as long as the MOSFET keeps switching on and off, but that's what I intended, since I want to charge the capacitor to a higher voltage. The final circuit will have a feedback network with a comparator to stop the switching once the desired cap voltage is reached.

Comment: As for the diode: Thanks! I didn't know about that. I'll look for a diode thats better suited for this job.

Comment: Also, to clarify what I meant by my predictions: I expected that, assuming an ideal diode, the current through cap and inductor when the switch is open could be modelled using an LC circuit. However, that does not appear to be the case. Now I'm wondering why that model is incorrect.

Comment: With the diode being there and the transistor going open circuit, the capacitor will have one continuous charging cycle up to the peak voltage and forever (until the transistor cycles again) will not receive any more charge.

Comment: Sorry, I was being unclear again: Once the capacitor is at peak voltage it will sit there until the transistor cycles again, I get that part. But the current while the capacitor is charging (i.e. until the current reaches zero) should still in theory match the current in an LC circuit, right?

Comment: Yes, OK I understand, it will match the current in an LC circuit.

Comment: Cool, thanks! So I guess my math is just wrong? I added a numerical example to illustrate the discrepancies between the math and the simulation.

Comment: I guess it must be wrong. Inductor current is blue I assume?

Comment: What would be a reasonable recovery time for a diode suited for this application?

Comment: A 1N4148 or a BAS16 has a reverse recovery time of below 10 ns but a 1 amp diode will be more like 100 ns. Schottky diodes are better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume the green wave is the voltage across the capacitor, and the blue wave is the current on the inductor, and that you charge the inductor from 0 to 45us.

So, first thing to notice: the capacitor's voltage has a bump on it. This shouldn't happen on ideal caps (I don't see infinite currents), so this must be the capacitor's series resistance.

Second thing to notice: if the voltage across the inductor is 0 at t=45us (if you simply assume "both the cap are at source are 5V, so 0V on inductor"), its current wouldn't be dropping. It is. That is probably because of the diode's voltage drop of about 0.7V when conducting forward hard (plus the cap's series resistance, but that only accounts for 5mV).

Basically, at those conditions, your circuit's dominant behavior is NOT an LC oscillator. That's more like "inductor with series diode". In fact, in boost converters, its mostly that or "inductor with series negative voltage source" when your cap is charged at, say, 10V.

You only really see LC waveforms if the capacitor charges significantly during a cycle, and that's just bad design.